# Google Analytics in footer file

Tags: templates, google-analytics

I have a question about how Google Analytics tracks pages in a Wordpress site or any other site that uses a template file to include the code for Google Analytics in the footer or header. Since the file is generated and used in all the pages, that would mean that the analytics code is counting all the pages that are viewed correct? Also, is it possible to view what pages are getting hits and have a more detailed report in Google Analytics? I just have a feeling that the page i'm tracking is displaying inaccurate reports since the same code is used on every page. Can anyone help clear this up and educate me a bit on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is always the same, it loads in the footer so you dont have to put it on every single page.

in the code there is a unique code for your website so analytics knows wich analytics account needs to get the information.

The code dosn't need to be changed everypage.

You can see the pageviews like this:

-->google analytics
--->contents 
-->Site content
-->all pages

Now you get a list with urls and the page view for every url

You can sort the list by pageviews (how many times is the page loaded) and unique page views(How many uniqe ip addresses have visited the page.).

You can also find bounce rate wich shows how many % of the users left you site on that page.

Comment: No problem if there are anymore questions feel free to ask.